# Wavelets beside the Daubechies- and Meyer-wavelet?

Tags: wavelets

- my first time asking a question on this forum.

I'm self studying the theory of wavelets.

I have one unanswered question regarding this; besides the Daubechies wavelets, Battle-Lemarié, and the Meyer wavelet, do we currently know of any other?

If yes, do any of them have a closed-form expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know of lots of wavelets.  Most do not have closed form expressions.

However see http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/705452/ for ones with a closed form expression.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a few are listed here here, but there are very many more:

1. [Legall & CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Daubechies%E2%80%93Feauveau_wavelet) are used in for example JPEG2000,
2. [Spline wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_wavelet) have been investigated lots by for example Michael Unser,
3. [Shannon wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_wavelet) which are boxes in Fourier domain - closely related to sincs in time domain,
4. [Morlet wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlet_wavelet) which are parts of exponential family.